# Editing a string in an Array

Tags: python, arrays

Hi assdabdbfz vgzgvdahdfbhjbshbvhbvhjbg ujnhunrgurgkjdfn vjguhuhfgjbfdnbvnmxbgruhugrhrgjrihuhrhjkjbg
   6      5     5     5     5      6 bits
    [  op  |  rs |  rt |  rd |shamt| funct]  R-type
    [  op  |  rs |  rt | address/immediate]  I-type
    [  op  |        target address        ]  J-type
    rs, rt, and rd indicate register operands; shamt gives a shift amount; and        the address or immediate fields contain an operand directly.

For example adding the registers 1 and 2 and placing the result in register 6 is encoded:

```
[  op  |  rs |  rt |  rd |shamt| funct]
    0     1     2     6     0     32     decimal
 000000 00001 00010 00110 00000 100000   binary
```

Comment: Please  do explain the program briefly.what is it doing?

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python.  Construct a new string with the desired contents.

Comment: I recommend adding more information. Like what debugging you've done, more info as to the intended action, lines of code you think/know you're having issues with, etc... Anyways, the `TextFile = userID +".txt"` seem fishy to me. Why not just add .txt to where your opening/creating the .txt file, before the following `if/try/except` statement? I know without debugging your code, that this works. `Username_input = input("...")+ ".txt"` also looks fishy. Keep the variable the same but then store that in another var that adds `".txt"` to it. You can't change the contents of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to append a separate array to the index, is that what you want to do here?

```
UserDetails[0].append(User)
```

Because `file.readlines()` pulls in a file as an array of strings, so if you are just trying to change that index you would use:

```
UserDetails[0] = usernamechange + "\n"   # assuming you break info by lines
```

---

Edit:

```
userList = UserDetails[0].split(',')     # turn your comma separated string into a list
userList[0] = usernamechange             # assuming the user name is the first change the user name
UserDetails[0] = ','.join(userList)      # turn the list back into a comma separated string and place it back in UserDetails
```

Comment: @SeanCousins, Formatting looks terrible in these comments so I'll edit my answer quick.

Comment: @SeanCousins I don't know how to answer without fully understanding what it is doing. Maybe start a new question with more information on it like output of prints and what the files look like internally.